# Graphics arch not exact

Tags: java, graphics2d

I have to draw precise archs in java. I am currenlty using Graphics2D.fillArc(). The problem is that it only accepts ints and the archs are not precise and i cant make the archs degree increase smoothly. Does anyone know a workaround this?

Comment: I think to help you best, we should see what isn't working for you, and the best way to show this is if you could create and post in an edit to your question a small compilable and runnable program that we can test and modify and that shows your problem directly for us, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  Best of luck!

Comment: Also, have you looked into using the Arc2D.Double class for your arcs?

Comment: Yes i just though of that 2 mins ago and implemented it. Thanks though. Put that in the answers and ill put it as the correct answer for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) using Arc2D.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChangingArcs extends JPanel {
   private static final Color ARC_FILL_COLOR = Color.RED;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
   private static final int ARC_X = 100;
   private static final int ARC_Y = 100;
   private static final int ARC_W = 500;
   private static final int ARC_H = 500;
   protected static final double DELTA_EXTEND = 0.5;
   private Arc2D arc;
   private double extend = 0;

   public ChangingArcs() {
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            extend += DELTA_EXTEND;
            extend %= 360;
            double start = -extend/2;
            arc = new Arc2D.Double(ARC_X, ARC_Y, ARC_W, ARC_H, start, extend, Arc2D.PIE);
            repaint();
         }
      }).start();
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(ARC_W + 2 * ARC_X, ARC_H + 2 * ARC_Y);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      if (arc != null) {
         g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         g2.setColor(ARC_FILL_COLOR);
         g2.fill(arc);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChangingArcs");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ChangingArcs());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @stas: I've not used Arc2D before, and so do this as a learning exercise.

Comment: @HFOE:  Great example.  If the color was yellow, it would look like a PacMan.  ;)